# because ‘flags of convenience’ nations tend to have little interest in regulation

Tags: phrase-meaning

Do *‘flags of convenience’ nations* refer to countries like the US, the EU nations? Or refer to nations like Bangladesh, Pakistan and India where ships are scrapped?

The problem in the understanding is that the ship owners with ships of the "flags of convenience" are of the US, the EU nations; so *the ‘flags of convenience’ nations* would refer to the US and the EU nations. but the phrase says "because ‘flags of convenience’ nations tend to have little interest in regulation" - Do the US and the EU nations have little interest in regulation? The opposite is true. Only Bangladesh, Pakistan and India etc. have little interest in regulation...

So it is puzzling me.

Sorry you may have to read more context in the link.

> “Business practices are rendering many international treaties and regional regulations unenforceable **because ‘flags of convenience’ nations tend to have little interest in regulation**,” says Wan. “In addition, workers’ health is always ignored by low-income nations that perform the ship-breaking.”

Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01391-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are flags of convenience?

This relates to ship registration and the answer is simple but the implication are not.

A. ***A flag of convenience ship is one that flies the flag of a country other than the country of ownership.***

"*‘flags of convenience’ nations*" are the Countries where the ships are registered not where their owners are located (see link below for a list of these countries).

---

***For workers onboard, this can mean:***

very low wages:
poor on-board conditions;
inadequate food and clean drinking water;
long periods of work without proper rest, leading to stress and fatigue

**By ‘*flagging out*’, ship owners can take advantage of:**

minimal regulation;
cheap registration fees;
low or no taxes;
freedom to employ cheap labour from the global labour market

Ref [flags of convenience](https://www.itfglobal.org/en/sector/seafarers/flags-of-convenience) Here you will find a **list of FOC countries**

Comment: Sorry. I knew what ‘flags of convenience' meant before posting the thread. It seems that you've not answered my question:   Do ‘flags of convenience’ nations refer to countries like the US, the EU nations? Or refer to nations like Bangladesh, Pakistan and India where ships are scrapped?  - What countries do the "nations" here refer to?

Comment: @NewPlanet There is a list of these countries in the link I provided. Please read the article.

Comment: Thank you.  That helps.